# refilling 5 liter Newcastle mini keg's

Tags: kegging

Can you refill an empty Newcastle or Heineken mini keg with your own home brew? I have recently purchased a "Koolatron" 5 liter mini keg system and want to know if my empty mini kegs can be filled with my own homemade beer.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is a CO2 cartridge inside those kegs that can not be removed without [cutting it open](http://www.themeparkreview.com/forum/files/germany_569_102.jpg).

However, some people have [used them anyway](http://www.thebrewingnetwork.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=&t=21461). But I would worry about cleaning a keg with a bunch of foreign objects inside.

Comment: .@Pepi is correct as to Heineken and Newcastle. However, other mini-kegs do not have the post inside (e.g., Bells' Oberon and Warsteiner lager), and you can also buy new 5L mini-kegs from many homebrew supply stores.